# How to Add Multiple VLOOKUPs with Multiple Columns in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I have multiple sections with the same name appearing in these sections. Along with each name is an entire row with different values. I'm looking to add the B column with the other section's B column corresponding to the same person. Then C with C, and so on until Z. In the end, I want one final row, adding all the other rows together.

With my current code, only the first column is added together. The other columns get ignored.

Note: This is for Google Sheets.

```
=ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("Doe, John",A16:Z35,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26},false))+ArrayFormula(VLOOKUP("Doe, John",A42:Z61,{2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26},false))
```

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11SiLpSy6aa0ImakYcheFdKrSA82oVD8YAJ6c7qqfCNw/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Row 286. Thank you. Will need to change name however. Fall Season tab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do it like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 VLOOKUP("Doe, John", A16:Z35, {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}, 0)+
 VLOOKUP("Doe, John", A42:Z61, {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26}, 0))
```

[image: 0]

---

btw, you could do it shorter like:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(
 VLOOKUP("Standera, Thomas", A16:Z35, COLUMN(B:Z), 0)+ 
 VLOOKUP("Standera, Thomas", A42:Z61, COLUMN(B:Z), 0))
```

Comment: Works perfect. Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to simplify this so only the name or column numbers have to be entered once?

Comment: Thank you. Is there a way to prevent "Error
Did not find value 'Doe, John' in VLOOKUP evaluation." if the name does not appear in a specific section? Just skip the section and not add anything to the total?

Comment: This will make the final row blank instead of an error. I would like the other valid sections to still be added to the total. Basically have any invalid sections add "0" to the total.

Comment: try: `=ARRAYFORMULA(
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP("xxx",              A16:Z35, COLUMN(B:Z), 0), COLUMN(B:Z)*0)+ 
 IFERROR(VLOOKUP("Standera, Thomas", A42:Z61, COLUMN(B:Z), 0), COLUMN(B:Z)*0))`